# Local runner for New Relic Scripted Browser

Tags: javascript, newrelic, scriptedbrowser

New Relic apparently came up with a foobar syntax for a service called [Scripted Browser](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/new-relic-synthetics/scripting-monitors/write-scripted-browsers)

I was looking to see if there was a local “Scripted Browser” runner or if you do actually need to load in code into the browser as the only means.

Answer (score 0):

I created a local runner for it.

- [GitHub](https://github.com/kirkstrobeck/scripted-browser)
- [Medium](https://medium.com/@kirkstrobeck/scripted-browser-37d3f354eca0#.8tn7f48mw)